# Equation of Simple Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I know that the differential equation of a simple harmonic oscillator is

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\omega^2x$

and it's solution is $y = A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$.

Now I learned for a solution with $n$ independent constants, the differential equation will be of order $n$.

In this case, there are 3 independent constants, $A, \omega, \phi$, so shouldn't the differential equation be of order three? How is it two?

Edit:

Also when I start with the solution itself

$y=A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$

$y'=A\omega\cos(\omega t + \phi)$

$\dfrac{\omega^2y^2}{A^2\omega^2}+\dfrac{y'^2}{A^2w^2} = 1$

$\omega^2\cdot2yy'+2y'y''=0$

$\omega^2=-\dfrac{y''}{y}$

$0=\dfrac{yy'''-y''y'}{y^2}$

$yy'''=y''y'$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A$ and $\phi$ are constants depending upon the initial conditions, which is consistent with the equation of order $2$, while $\omega$ depends solely upon the system that is the given equation $\ddot x=-\omega x$.

Comment: Perhaps of interest,:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/shm2.html

Comment: Gimusi.Your answer is nice!The link "links" omega and the spring constant.

Comment: But like if I try to find the differential equation of the given solution by eliminating the constants, I land up at a third order equation $yy'''-y''y'$, so why is that?

Comment: @HarshitJoshi differentiating and manipulating $\ddot x=-\omega x$ we obtain $\dddot x=-\omega \dot x \implies x\dddot x=-\omega x\dot x =\ddot x\dot x \implies x\dddot x-\ddot x\dot x=0$ but that doesn't prove anything. The given ODE has 2 free constants which depends upon the initial condition $x(0)$ and $\dot x(0)$.

Comment: No I started with the solution $y=Asin(\omega t+\phi)$ itself. Should I include the working in the post?

Comment: @HarshitJoshi Yes it should be useful to understand better what you are claiming.

Comment: Actually I think I get it, if $\omega$ is a property the system, then performing the second last step is unnecessary as $\omega$ will not be an arbitrary constant anymore.

Comment: @HarshitJoshi Note also that $$y=A\sin(\omega t + \phi) \implies y'=A\omega\cos(\omega t + \phi) \implies y''=-A\omega^2\sin (\omega t + \phi)=-\omega^2 y$$ which is the original equation. Of course if we  differentiate further we obtain equations of order $3,4,...$ but in any case $\omega$ is a inherent constant of the system.

Comment: @HarshitJoshi Exactly $\omega$ is not an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 3):

The constant $\omega$ is given in the equation, you mustn't count it. What you count are the *adjustable* constants, that you can freely tune to achieve the initial conditions.